# Magento2: Issue with label "new" for configurable product

Tags: magento2

I have any issue with display label "new" only for configurable product.
Displays in the same place where the % discount is

[image]

Anyone help me how can I move to little down orange label with % discount?

@update
Here is configurable product and you see % discount:
[image]

Here is simple product and magento not shows % discount:
[image]

Comment: any chance for link to the website? Probably a simple CSS issue.

Comment: czasowewyprzedaze.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below css and it will fix the issue.

```
span.product-label.sale-label.sale-label-config {
    margin-top: 34px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: John, thank you. Your solution solve our issue. But one more question. Now the magento not shows sale % label on product card for Simple product (example: bags).

Comment: on products list: shows % discount for configurable product and simple product | on product page shows % discount for configurable product but not shows for simple product

Comment: can't understand, what you mean. Can you provide me a screenshot or a page link point to?

Comment: ok, can you point to those two types of products? simple and configurable.

Comment: I have update my topic

Comment: it looks like there were some calculations problem in your price.phtml file for simple products or there might no discount price to be display for simple products as per your theme. In order to do that,  you need to add custom code for simple products to show discounted price as configurable products.